# Profiling asp.net application - You do not have any binaries chosen for sampling

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, profiling

When profiling an asp.net web application I get the error message "you do not have any binaries chosen for sampling."  If I continue anyhow the web page will run and the profiler appears to be running as well.  However when the profiler is stopped, no data is collected.  I am choosing the option "An ASP.NET or JavaScript application."
If instead I do the following steps listed below, then only javascript functions in my asp.net MVC application get profiled. What am I doing wrong here? The web application is being run in IIS and the target framework of the application is .net 3.5 if that helps any.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition as well.

1. Run the Visual Studio with Administrator permission,
2. Performance Wizard -- Page 1 of 4 -> Instrumentation
3. Performance Wizard -- Page 2 of 4 -> An ASP.NET or JavaScript application
4. Performance Wizard -- Page 3 of 4 -> Write down the URL, and choose the "Profile JavaScript" option.